# Maneira correta de retornar o o número de resultados utilizando o CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, count

Escrevi 2 possibilidades de retornar o número de resultados utilizando o CodeIgniter, segue:

```
public function get_num_indicados($id_usuario)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(id_patrocinador) as num FROM usuarios WHERE id_patrocinador = ?", array($id_usuario));

    $row = $query->row();

    return $row->num;
}

public function get_num_indicados($id_usuario)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_patrocinador = ?", array($id_usuario));

    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

**Dúvida:** Qual a maneira correta e porque? É indiferente? E quanto a performance para o MySQL?

Comment: Amigo, normalmente eu uso qualquer uma das duas, mas também uso o count($this->model->function()); que resolve também...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duas maneiras de ser obter o número total de resultados da tabela do banco de dados então corretas, pois por mais que elas estejam escritas de formas diferentes elas então chegando ao mesmo fim a qual elas foram criadas.

Mas em questão de performance, a primeira é mais rápida, pois a consulta no banco de dados só retorna a quantidade total de registros na tabela **usuarios** com a função **count** do MySql, enquanto o segundo método retorna os registros do banco que não seram usados e em seguida é feito a contagem dos registros com o método **num_rows** do CI.

Caso a quantidade de registros na tabela **usuarios** seja pouca a diferença de performance pode ser indiferente, mas caso a tabela tenha muitos registros a diferença pode se notável no desempenho.